# Word for someone who appreciates vintage items because of history behind them

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is a word for someone who appreciates vintage items because of the history behind them? For example: someone who enjoys listening to records and wonders who in a past life listened to it, what they were doing when listening to it, etc.

Comment: 'Sentimentalist' is a hypernym but may be of use.

Comment: @jasperloy regarding your edit - inversions in embedded questions such as "wonder [...] what were they doing" are a very common dialectal occurrence.

Comment: Are you looking for *retrophile*?

Comment: Or maybe "antiquarian"?

Comment: @BlaiseZydeco You should add 'antiquarian' as the answer

Comment: @publicwireless Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

A word that works for the questioner's purpose is *antiquarian*. The [Webster's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antiquarian) is just the bare-bones "somebody who studies antiquities", but the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiquarian) goes a little farther and says "aficionado or student of antiquities or things of the past."

The first paragraph of this [article on antiquarianism by urban historian Roey Sweet](http://www.history.ac.uk/makinghistory/resources/articles/antiquarianism.html) is also of some interest here.